# Promises + async.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async.js

I always read that using Promises with async.js is not a good idea. I would like to understand why.

I'm working in a project that i'm using async.eachLimit to control the limit of async operation in files, and Promises to return the result after i finish all the async operations. Example:

```
const maxOfAsync = process.env.maxOfAsync || 500;

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
  async.eachLimit(arrayOfFiles, maxOfAsync, (file, callback) => {
    callExternalLib(file).then((data) => {
      file.data = data;
      callback();
    }).catch((error) => {
      callback(error);
    });
  }, (error) {
    if (error) return reject(error);
    resolve(arrayOfFiles);
  });
});
```

If i should not use both together, how to achieve the same result? Let's forget about async/await for a minute and return to the days that only Promises and async.js exists. What could i do?

Thanks.

Comment: "*do something asynchronous*" uses promises as well, I suppose?

Comment: That's basically the same way I'm combining the both.

Comment: Yes, definitly.

Comment: I updated the question @Bergi

Comment: "`.reject(reject);`" definitely looks wrong already

Comment: I updated @Bergi. I confused with catch, sorry.

Comment: I mean, just look at that code. "Bad idea" I think just reflects that *async.js* predates promises, and was designed with callbacks in mind. Why not pick a more promise-friendly library? Personally, I'd just reimplement the few tricks I needed from it. Concurrency control isn't as hard a problem as it used to be, at least with `async`/`await`. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Bluebird's [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) allows you to step over an Iterable and set a concurrency.

```
return Promise.map(arrayOfFiles, file => {  
  return callExternalLib(file).then((data) => {
    file.data = data;
    return file;
  }
}, { concurrency: maxOfAsync })
```

Promise.map will resolve a new array of values once all promises are resolved. It's not a requirement to mutate an existing array like the original code and the example above is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that combining async callback syntax with promise syntax can confusing code. I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with it. If my code is all using promises and I introduce a library that uses callbacks, I would usually wrap that library with promises to keep my code clean.

Answer (score 0):

Async.js is kind of "meh" when you want to use promises. It's good at what is does but is clearly a library that was built to ease the use of callbacks and that was later upgraded to try to work with promises. It even tries to make some auto-magic decompilation of the code to try to know if a function should be handled like an async function returning a promise or a non-async function using a callback (and, like all libraries making decompilation, it can and will fail if you compile your code with Babel or similar tools).

I recently published a library which is an alternative to async.js and that was precisely made to use only Promises (and async/await), thus making a fully-consistant library to work using those newer tools.

The result is named modern-async and is here: https://nicolas-van.github.io/modern-async/